# şapka and шапка - which way did the hat travel?

Tags: etymology, russian, turkish

The russian and turkish words for **hat** : **şapka** and **шапка** are very similar.

It makes me suspect that one language borrowed it from the other.

Which way did the hat travel?

Comment: Look here: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C5%9Fapka and here https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0#Russian to get the story: It originated in French, travelled via Russia to Turkey

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks basic research, in this case a wiktionary lookup.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica. If Wiktionary is correct. Nişanyan derives the Turkish word from Arabic and Semitic. https://www.nisanyansozluk.com/?k=%C5%9Fapka

Comment: @fdb very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @fdb: Interesting, but the meaning of the Arabic word ist "fishing net" and derived from that "knit veil", this would be quite a semantic shift to "hat"

Comment: Nishanyan provides quotes from 500 years ago, before there was much Russian influence in Anatolia or French influence on Russian.  That doesn't support the Arabic theory but it supports re-opening this question.

Comment: Bulgarian Wiktionary: **старобълг. *шапка в шапкы фрѫшскыѫ „френски шапки“ (Грамота на Мирчо Велики, 1413 г.). Заета по времето на кръстоносните походи от диал. старофр. chappe, фр. chapeau < лат. cappa „плащ с качулка“.**

Comment: Given that the word was in Stambul Armenian only (but not in Armenia until much later directly from Russian, hence *šapka* not *šapxa*), the proximity of Bulgaria, the South Slavic population and churches in Constantinople and Thrace before the genocide of the Rum millet and modern assimilation of Bosniaks and Pomaks, Bulgarian seems like a more likely candidate for the immediate source.

Comment: -ка (and -ко) is one of the Bulgarian diminutives (whereas in Western South Slavic it is not productive).

Comment: It's rare that a French word shows up in East Slavic and South Slavic but not in German, Dutch or West Slavic.